# MongoDB filter record by created date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to filter records by created date ? The problem is, i don't have a date field. But does mongoDB keep insertion date by itself and can i filter it by specific two dates ?

Comment: Basically, if you have **not** overridden the usage of `ObjectId` values for `_id`, then you can *sort of* do it. But you hinging on the reliability that the "insertion" actually recorded this value at the correct point in time and you also give up millisecond precision. If you want **reliable** "date queries", then you should **always** store at least one value as a  BSON date field within the document.